# Vue js - Passing data to a prop in a component in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this app to make I am dealing with the CRUD and only the *"U(pdate)"* is posing problems
I have :

```
<template>
<EditQuestion 
        v-show="showEditQ"
        :questToEdit="questToEdit"
        />
</template> 
<script>
import EditQuestion from '../components/EditQuestion'
export default {
  
name: 'Home',
  
  components: {
     EditQuestion
  },
  data() {
    return {
    questToEdit:{},
    }
  },
methods:{
async getQuestion(_id){
      const questToEdit = await this.fetchQuestion(_id)
      return questToEdit
},
async fetchQuestion(_id) {
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/questions/${_id}`)
        const data = await res.json()
        return data

    },
}
</script>
```

and in the component side I have

```
<template>
    <div>
    <p>test</p>
    
    <p>{{questToEdit.question}}</p>
            <li 
            v-for="(proposition,index) in questToEdit.propositions" 
            :key="index"  
            >{{proposition.props}}
            </li>
    
    
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'EditQuestion',
    props: {
        questToEdit:Object
    },
    data(){
      return {
        
    }
    },
  
}
</script>
```

I feel like I can't access questToEdit in the component (it's doing nothing ) or its never called on home ? thx for your time in advence.

Comment: Hi, Can you share a codepen which will help in debugging the issue more easily.

Comment: where you're setting the value for this "showEditQ" variable?

Comment: @tonytom in the app.vue upper in the app

Comment: I am afraid it's not clear what your problem is. You mention that you have problems updating something, but there's nowhere in your code an update happening in any way - you are just fetching data and display it in a list. You need to be much more specific about what you are trying to achieve, what you have already tried, and what you need from us.

Comment: @thomasKuhlmann sorry if i am not clear the problem is that the data wont appear in the liste or upper une the <p>{{questToEdit.question}}</p> it is like the OBJECT questToEdit is not passed to the component . and the object is setup like this ```questToEdit:{
          question:'une question',
          propositions:[
            {props:'reponce 1',correct:'true'},
            {props:'reponce 2',correct:'false'},
            {props:'reponce 3',correct:'false'},
            {props:'reponce 4',correct:'false'}]
          }```

Comment: That's ok, you just need to spend a bit of time bringing your question into a format that makes sense to the rest of us. The code you added isn't really helping - here's a good article that walks you through the process of writing a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/